# setting field error in <input title=""> html tag in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in my HTML. I would like to use django form validations and form handling however I need that the error provided by django will be placed in the title of the input tag.

I would like to use the

```
{{form.username}}
```

but I need the error inside the input like:

```
<input id="id_username" name="username" value="" type="text" title="This field is required" value="User Name" />
```

Anyway I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Put `{{ form.fieldname.errors.as_text }}` inside the input, as desired.

Comment: but then I cant use the {{form.fieldname}} syntax. I'll have to write the input field without the help of django.. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Nuno_147 I don't think I'm following.. You _don't_ want to use django to render the template?

Comment: I do. You suggest that I'll do <input id="id_username" title="{{form.fieldname.errors.as_text }} >. doing that, will break django rendering because I'll have to write the <input> tag directly in the HTML without using django template rending. I want that the {{form.fieldname}} syntax will include the error in the title if there is an error, without me breaking the input tag down.

Comment: Btw, the only solution I have for this now is to use javascript. so I'll use the {{form.fieldname}} but on a javascript code I will set the title element of each field id with the error like $("{{form.fieldname.id}}").attr("title","{{form.fieldname.errors.as_text}} but thats ugly...

Comment: @Nuno_147 What you want is not to use `{{ form.as_* }}` but instead write your custom form view. That would be the cleanest way to do it, if you don't want to do it the js way you mentioned. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template).